# Formal conditions on classes of mappings $f$, as in $y=f(x)$, that can NOT be inferred from $\{x,y\}$ data

Tags: machine-learning

A large class of machine learning problems are posed as regression/inference problems trying solve for the mapping $f: X \rightarrow  Y$, with  $y \in Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, from finite subsets :  $\hat{X}=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_T\} \subset X$ and $ \hat{Y}=\{y_1,y_2,...,y_T\} \subset Y$

While there is much discussion on how to compute $f$ from $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$, I have not been able to find much theory discussing mathematical structure of the spaces $X$ and $Y$, aside from the trivial case of linear subspaces, as related to computability of the mapping $f$. Are there certain mappings that are not computable from $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{Y}$, and ultimately, why? With that said, my question here is the following:

Are there formal conditions on classes of $f$ to indicate that it can NOT be inferred/learned from the finite subsets  $\hat{X}$  and $ \hat{Y}$, regardless of the size, $T$, or the choice of the subsets?

Posed slightly differently, in terms of $X$ and $Y$, are there topological properties of $X$ and $Y$ that would influence recovery of $f$ from $\hat{X}$  and $ \hat{Y}$? Thanks much in advance.

Comment: It will be difficult to give comprehensive answers, but intuitively the (relative) topologies of $X$ and $Y$ tell us little.  What matters is the space of permissible functions $f:X\to Y.$ But unless $f$ is at least continuous (with some control over the amount of variation, such as Lipschitz continuity) or assumed to come from a fairly "rigid" family of functions (in some sense), there is no basis to infer anything about its values except where it has been observed.

Comment: Thank you @whuber, v. insightful start. Lipschitz continuity is a great one for recover-ability, I'd it put up there with linear subspaces. Yet, we seem to infer plenty from spaces that would fail the test. I know it's hard, but grossly simplified, I am looking for any, rough/in-comprehensive as it may be, insight akin to rank conditions, for X in particular, as they would exist in the space of in linear mappings Y=FX. If not topology in this case,  what other directions could we look to explore and expand?

Comment: All I can do is repeat myself, emphasizing the alternative about a small family of functions.  For instance, it's easy to fit a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ of the form $f(x)=\beta_0 + \beta_1(x - \lfloor x-\mu\rfloor)$ to data even though such functions have many discontinuities that can occur at any location. And therein lies the problem with the question: it's so vague and general that it admits many rather different, but still correct, answers.